# How do I separate client, API, admin in Node.js & React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I will use React for client and admin panel, Node.js for API. I'm stuck somewhere. I don't want them dependent on each other. How can I separate each of these 3 projects into different folders?

- Client: domain.com
- Admin Panel: domain.com/admin
- API: domain.com/api

Note: Client and Admin Panel are different React apps.

Comment: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone the repositories onto your server and build your React apps (i.e. `npm run build` on the terminal. Look at your package.json file to check if it's the same command).

For the front end, use Nginx. If you're using a Linux server, use [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) tutorial from Digital Ocean. Link your React apps to /var/www/ directory and have the Nginx serve your website from the build directory in your apps (i.e. `root /var/www/domain.com/build` in the server block) after you created the config file (i.e. /etc/nginx/sites-available/domain.com). Link the /etc/nginx/sites-available to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled.

Try using [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-18-04) tutorial for putting your node application into production. I was also stuck on adding the API until I figured out reverse proxy on Nginx works as you said. Use pm2 to run your API in the background.
Check for any errors with `sudo nginx -t` then run `sudo systemctl restart nginx` to restart Nginx.

Comment: Thank you! I solved it out this way: [link](https://gist.github.com/ozgurg/a64de4672c60b13dbed8888731056417)

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you want to connect Admin panel and client website through API with a different folder project.

1. create sub-domain for dashboard URL: panel.domain.com
2. create sub-domain for nodejs API URL: api.domain.com
3. already you have public_html directory on your panel for domain.com

and then in Reactjs client or Admin Panel you can set `CRUD`  method using Restful API install `axios` npm package in Reactjs project.

```
import axios from 'axios'
   axios.get('http://api.domain.com/get-all-users').then(response => {
   consol.log(response.data);
));
```

also you can CRUD all data from database by using axios